# How to center a form using grid in react

Tags: css, reactjs, grid

I have a react component which contains a `typography` and a `form`.
The code of my component was [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wo5nxvnvz5).

There is a lag between the title `Add new User` and the form. I want to shift the form to the right in order to be centered with the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have updated the codesandbox, title and form both are aligned under one column.
https://codesandbox.io/s/r782xm30po

[image]

Comment: Sorryy I get the same display as mine. Could you mentioned me the changes that you made and what are the lines matching them in the updated file.

Comment: you want remove space between title and form ?

Comment: I want to shift the form to the right in order to be centered with the title

Comment: I have got it now and fixed it as per the requirement.